# Счетчик уникальных просмотров через Cookie

Tags: php, cookie

Необходим счетчик уникальных просмотров статей, создаю такой с использованием Cookie. При посещении каждой статьи пользователю в Cookie заносится ID этой статьи со значением "1" и временем жизни в 1 день. В дальнейшем, если пользователь просматривает статью, ID которой сохранено в Cookie, просмотр не засчитывается.

На сайте планируется довольно много статей. Что со скоростью работы такого метода?

Comment: Куки-то не резиновые, чтобы в них для каждой статьи писать информацию.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В принципе, так никто не заморачивается.
Даже стандартные системы сбора статистики не считают уникальных посетителей за все время, а только за сутки. За двое суток в графе "уникальные посетители" они показывают сумму уникальных за каждый день, а не просто уники за два дня (которых будет ощутимо меньше).

Если хочется ставить уникальную куку, то обновлять БД несложно

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE['views'.$_GET['id']])) {
    setcookie(...);
    $pdo->prepare("UPDATE posts SET views=views+1 WHERE id=?")->execute([$_GET['id']]);
}
```

Но тут есть несколько засад.

- Во-первых, кук на все статьи не напасёшься. Можно, конечно, ставить просто одну уникальную куку и сделать отдельную таблицу просмотров, куда писать уникальный идентификатор из куки и ид статьи, и потом считать количество строк. Но это будет раздувать количество хранимых данных, не говоря уже о том, что способ все равно неидеальный.
- Во-вторых, есть клиенты, которые не поддерживают куки. А, к примеру, большинство поисковых ботов делают это намеренно. А ходят по сайту при этом часто.

В общем, интернет так устроен что 100% верную цифру ты не получишь всё равно, а колготни будет много. Так что я бы на твоем месте либо просто писал все просмотры, либо - если хочется какой-то точности, но только для себя - наладить ивент в Гугл аналитикс и заходить вечерами получать удовольствие на него.

Comment: Да, с Cookies такие проблемы... А если ставить их для конкретной страницы, а не для всего сайта? Указывать адрес страницы вместо "/" в параметре. Это не спасет ситуацию?

Comment: @nup, всё что в данном случае можно сделать - подсчитывать общее количество посещений страницы и заносить в БД, без учёта уникальности посетителя. Остальные варианты ресурсо-затратны.

Answer (score 0):

Легче лёгкого.

```
$id_my_post = trim($_GET['id_post']);
$id_my_post = strip_tags($id_my_post);
if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $id_my_post = stripslashes($id_my_post);
}
$id_my_post = htmlspecialchars($id_my_post, ENT_QUOTES);
if(!is_numeric($id_my_post) || $id_my_post < 0 || strlen($id_my_post) > 9) { exit; }
$id_my_post = mysql_real_escape_string($id_my_post);

if(!isset($_COOKIE[$id_my_post])) {
    $get_number_of_views_post = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT `views` FROM `tab_posts` WHERE `id_post`=".$id_my_post ." LIMIT 1"));
    mysql_query("UPDATE `tab_posts` SET `views`=".($get_number_of_views_post['views']+1)." WHERE `id_post`=".$id_my_post ." LIMIT 1");
    setCookie($id_my_post, '1', time()+24*60*60, '/', 'your_domain.com',0,true); // выставляем COOKIES для этой записи на 24 часа
}
```

Остаётся только подставить сюда свои данные. Но я бы не в коем случае не делал на основе COOKIES. Это медленная смерть. Так как у Вас может накопиться огромное количество статей. И для каждой статьи хранить COOKIES? НЕт, так не делают.

Comment: Тому кто поставил "-1" огромная просьба изложить свою великомудрую точку зрения.

Comment: прямо молодостью повеяло... Я такой прошаренный код в прошлом веке писал, гордился сильно. Почти 20 лет прошло. А ПХП всё такой же. Цветёт и пахнет. `*смахнул скупую слезу*`

Comment: @Ипатьев, так ведь это, на пенсию значит пора. А если ещё есть порох в пороховницах и ягоды в ягодицах, то любезно опишите мои ошибки в составлении кода. Я "очень долго" их буду изучать и совершенствоваться.

Comment: Stack Overflow - не форум, и не онлайн-курсы. Здесь ничего не изучают. Здесь пишут ответы на вопросы. Заданные в установленном порядке, и отвечающие установленным правилам.

Comment: @Ипатьев, правила.. Кто играет по правилам? Правила существуют для тех, кто их соблюдает. Коли старый-мудрый, должен это понимать. Так могу я Вас любезно изложить своё мнение на счёт построения кода? В чём, как вы говорите его "прошаренность"?